# How to require a trait in another trait correctly?

Tags: rust

I tried to write two traits where one requires another to be implemented and got this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: ValTrait` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:20:1
   |
20 | / fn get<T: ValRequireTrait + std::fmt::Debug>(_t: T) {
21 | |     println!("{:?}", T::VAL);
22 | | }
   | |_^ the trait `ValTrait` is not implemented for `T`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where T: ValTrait` bound
   = note: required by `ValRequireTrait`
```

[The code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3eaf27b96d59eddfec085a90687053cb&version=stable):

```
trait ValTrait<T = Self> {
    const VAL: T;
}

trait ValRequireTrait<T: ValTrait = Self> {}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct A {
    field: u64,
}

impl ValTrait for A {
    const VAL: A = A {
        field: 0u64
    };
}
impl ValRequireTrait for A {}


fn get<T: ValRequireTrait + std::fmt::Debug>(_t: T) {
    println!("{:?}", T::VAL);
}

fn main() {
    let a = A { field: 6u64 };
    get(a);
}
```

How to do this correctly? If I do what the compiler says I will not need the `ValRequireTrait` because it will be useless. I wanted `ValRequireTrait` to be a mark that the structure implements enough methods as I need.

In other words, I expect such a requirement be transitive so when in `get()` function I require one trait (`ValRequireTrait`), others (`ValTrait`) will be required automatically without any specification in the code as compiler wants.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds like you want `ValTrait` to be a **supertrait** of `ValRequireTrait`. A good introduction can be found in [the Rust book (2nd edition)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#supertraits-to-use-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait):

> Sometimes, we may want a trait to be able to rely on another trait also being implemented wherever our trait is implemented, so that our trait can use the other trait’s functionality. The required trait is a supertrait of the trait we’re implementing.

If you change this line:

```
trait ValRequireTrait<T: ValTrait = Self> {}
```

to this, it compiles fine:

```
trait ValRequireTrait<T: ValTrait = Self>: ValTrait<T> {}
```

Comment: Looks ridiculous to me repeat one thing many times. Is there any explanation of why it was made so? I mean, we have already required `T` to be `ValTrait`, why to require `ValRequireTrait` to be `ValTrait`? I see a repetition here.

Comment: Your are right it is redundant and the compiler manages to infer the trait bounds itself. You don't have to specify the trait bound explicitely. This works as well: `trait ValRequireTrait<T = Self>: ValTrait<T> {}`. I am not a rust expert myself, I am currently learning myself. In general I found that the [rfcs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs) contain valuable information on *why* things are done in a specific way. I didn't find anything relevant on supertraits though.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy `ValRequireTrait` is nearly useless because it's parameterized the same way `ValTrait` is. I suspect you're looking for `trait ValRequireTrait : Sized + ValTrait {}` (no parameter on `ValRequireTrait`). [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d1a5cbda10d5b63e6082b8caada49911&version=stable)

Comment: ([`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html) and [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) have the same relationship, where `Eq` requires `PartialEq<Self>`.)

Comment: @trentcl you are right but only for this my example. My real usage has parameters and it needs to have a template parameter. But thank you for noticing this too.

Comment: Updated book link: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html

Answer (score 10):

The solution I was looking for is [supertraits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait).

```rust
trait Foo{
  fn hello(&self);
}

trait Bar{
  fn world(&self);
}

trait Baz: Foo + Bar {
  fn say_hi(&self){
    self.hello()
    self.world()
  }
}
```